# Suggestions with Throw dice program

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, throw, dice

I am trying to build a new application where I can with the help of a parameter know how many times the dice must be thrown before you can get the number of sixes from the parameter. Hope you understand.I am quite new in this so please help me.

Here is my code:

```
package programe;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    sixes(5);   
}

public static void sixes(int x){    

int roll = 0;
int dice;
int count;

Random random = new Random();

for(count = 1; count <= roll; count++){

    dice = 1 + random.nextInt(6);
    System.out.println("It takes " + roll + "before you get" + x + " sixes in a row");
}

}
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand how to set up the programe to count how many times it must roll before it can get the sixes stored in the parameter...

Comment: You want to know how often you must throw the dice to get 5(x) sixes?

Comment: Yes. I want to programe that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem didnt let me think about other stuff so i decided to solve it and its done.

Here is the code:

```
public class Dice {


public static String sixes(int x){

    int rolls = 0;

    String sixesRow =" ";
    String result = "";

    Random r = new Random();

    while(true){

        rolls++;
        int rDice = r.nextInt(7);
        if (rDice == 6){
            if(sixesRow.charAt(sixesRow.length()-1) == '6' || sixesRow.charAt(0) == ' '){
                sixesRow.replace(' ', '6');
                String sixesRowCurrent = sixesRow.concat("6");
                sixesRow = sixesRowCurrent;
            }

            if(rowCheck(sixesRow, x)){
                result = "Took " + rolls + " throws to get " + x + " sixes in a row!";
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            String sixesRowCurrent = sixesRow.concat("0");
            sixesRow = sixesRowCurrent; 
        }
    }
    return result;
}


public static boolean rowCheck(String sixesRow, int x){

    boolean xTimesRow = false;
    String testString = ""; 
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){

        String loopString = testString.concat("6");
        testString = loopString;
    }   
    if(sixesRow.contains(testString)){
        xTimesRow = true;
    }   
    return xTimesRow;
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Please insert the amount of sixes in a row: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sixes = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println(sixes(sixes));
}
}
```